# React ref is undefined after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
import { StepData } from "@/components/steptree/StepData";
import { Input } from "@material-tailwind/react";
import { RegisterValidateHandler } from "./DataHandler";
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

export function StartDataHandler({stepData, validator} : {stepData: StepData, validator : RegisterValidateHandler}) {
    
    const [error, setError] = React.useState("");
    let testInputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();

    validator(() => {
        //this arrow function gets called whenever I click a certain 
        //button
        console.log("testInputRef value: ", testInputRef.current?.value);
        if (testInputRef.current?.value == "test") {
            return true;
        } else {
            //once setError is called, testinputRef.current is 
            //undefined forever
            setError("testInputRef is empty");
            return false;
        }
    });

    return (
        <div>
            {error != "" && <h2>{error}</h2>}
            <input ref={testInputRef} type="text" placeholder="test start"/>
            {/* <Input ref={testInputRef} label="test start"/> */}
        </div>
    )
}
```

The arrow function passed to `validator()` is called externally after clicking on a button.
When I click the button and the input value is "test" then it always keeps the latest value of the input element. Once `setError` is called (value is not 'test') then testInputRef.current is undefined forever no matter how often I change the input value and click the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the ref persisted in your component's instance data, use the [`useRef`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) hook, not `createRef`.

```
const testInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```